# How to omit data in navigation property in Web-Api without [JsonIgnore] or [IgnoreDataMember] attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, properties

I would like to know how to omit specific property from being serialized.
The problem is I cannot use `[JsonIgnore]` or `[IgnoreDataMember]` attributes beacause I need this property to be displayed somewhere else.

Here are my service models

```
public class Event
{
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
    public string EventLocalization { get; set; }        
    public string EventImage { get; set; }
    public string EventUrl { get; set; }
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

When I ask for JSON from event I get back something like this:

```
[
  {
    "EventId": 1,
    "EventName": "Alalala",
    "EventDate": "2016-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EventLocalization": "Musialka",
    "EventImage": null,
    "EventUrl": null,
    "EventDescription": null,
    "City": {
      "CityId": 164,
      "CityName": "Opole",
      "State": {
        "StateId": 8,
        "StateName": "opolskie",
        "Cities": null
      },
      "Events": null
    },
    "Category": {
      "CategoryId": 1,
      "CategoryName": "Teatr i Opera"
    }
  }
]
```

And here is the loop. City model consists of Event navigation property but I dont want to display again Events when I ask for event's JSON. I would like to display only `CityId`, `CityName` and `State` properties. I cannot decorate `IEnumerable<Event>` property in City model because I need this property to return event's list when I ask for City JSON.

I figured out I can create another model just with 3 properties: `CityId`, `CityName` and `State` and include it as property in Event model instead of City property, but with 50 models it is quite a huge work.

Can I solve this problem in any other way?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a class City

```
    public class City 
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public string CityName { get; set; }

        public State State { get; set; }
    }
```

and a class CityWithEvents

```
    public class CityWithEvents : City
    {
       public IEnumerable<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
```

In the class Event you need to store reference to the class City, and in any time if you need to show City Events initialize the class CityWithEvents